# cannot convert dictionary update sequence element

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to use python map function to get user by id but i have this error
how to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to convert to a `dict`? What is your desired output?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. They are not accessible to screen readers or search and anyone that want to help has to retype your code.

Comment: users_3={'id':'3','username':'houssem','password':'789'}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- The lambda expression here returns a boolean value True or False.
- The map function returns a map object which when converted to a list.
  results in `[False, False, False]`.
- You can't convert this to a dictionary hence the error.
- Also id() is a built-in function dont use it as an argument.

If op is trying to get the user object by id I suggest you use this function

```
def get(search_key, users):
    for user in users:
        if int(user['id']) == search_key:
            return user

get(7, users)
```